# aspx page using Input type Email

Tags: c#, html, validation, input, types

I have a textbox in a WebForm aspx page

```
<input ID="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" style="Font-Size:20px"  placeholder="Email" Type="Email" runat="server" />
```

But it keeps giving me error that `'Email' is not a valid type for an input tag.`
 Weird enough it shows the option `Email` when I enter the word in the input tag `Type=` It shows `Email` as an option but then again says No such thing as email I need to use this to see if the entered email is ending with `@Email.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `txtemail.Attributes.Add("type", "email");`

If you try to use that like `txtEmail.Attributes("type") = "email"` Like 
@Scath mentioned it will not work because  It's a property, not a method

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" type="email" id="emailtextbox" />
```

This works for me.

If it doesn't for you, you can add the attribute by hand like this:

```
emailtextbox.Attributes["type"] = "email";
```